# How to install postgresql and phppgadmin with nginx?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, phppgadmin

I need to install postgresql and phppgadmin with nginx installed under ubuntu 16(AWS)
I installed packages :

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib phppgadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
phppgadmin is already the newest version (5.1+ds-1ubuntu1).
postgresql is already the newest version (9.5+173ubuntu0.2).
postgresql-contrib is already the newest version (9.5+173ubuntu0.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

in phpinfo I see drivers installed
http://ec2-18-224-82-207.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/info.php

```
PostgreSQL driver for PDO   Edin Kadribasic, Ilia Alshanetsky
PostgreSQL  Jouni Ahto, Zeev Suraski, Yasuo Ohgaki, Chris Kings-Lynne
```

But running phppgadmin in url like :
http://ec2-18-224-82-207.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/phppgadmin
I got error :

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Searching for decision I found that  /etc/nginx/sites-available/phppgadmin  directory, but :

```
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-88:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 18 05:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 12 15:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2327 Jun 17 12:02 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2074 Jun 12 15:49 default.bak
```

Which steps I have to take to run phppgadmin and laravel 5 app ?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Installation**

First, install postgreSQL and phpPgAdmin.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib phppgadmin php5-fpm
```

And then, lets install Nginx.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

This should automatically start Nginx as the web server. You could also type this to start the service.

```
sudo service nginx start
```

**2. Setup PostgreSQL & phpPgAdmin**

First login as the Postgres user and lets create a new Postgres role (user)

```
sudo su postgres
createuser -P --interactive
```

--interactive - adds some initial permissions
-P            - means assign a password

The default installation of phpPgAdmin will automatically connect to PostgreSQL server. Unless you have modified any configuration, you can leave this as is.

**3. Setup Nginx**

First, lets add a symbolic link to the directory where you intend to place all your web files in.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin /path/to/your/www
```

Next, lets create a server block for phpPgAdmin. Create a file /etc/nginx/sites-available/phppgadmin with the following contents.

```
# Server block for phppgadmin service
server{
        server_name     phppgadmin.example.com;
        root            /path/to/your/www/phppgadmin;

        access_log      /var/log/phppgadmin/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/phppgadmin/error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/your/www/postgres$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

By default Nginx includes all the servers in the folder `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. So lets add a symbolic link to the new server we created to let nginx know about our new server!

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/phppgadmin /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Now all that is left to do is to restart/reload Nginx and our phpPgAdmin is ready to go!

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Make sure you've included theese in nginx.conf file.

```
index   index.php index.htm index.html;
root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
```